# How do I combine .tif files without tiffcp

Tags: 16.04, pdf, convert

I have 536 .tif files. I want to join them and convert the output file into a pdf file.

Now the problems which I am facing are:

1. `tiffcp` gives an error: `Unknown field with tag 32934 (0x80a6) encountered`
2. I tried converting all the files to jpeg and then combining but using `convert` on all the files at once freezes the computer.

The issue with `tiffcp` may have to do something with the file itself so, I *guess* nothing is possible to solve that.

But I was successful converting individual files to .jpeg using `convert`. 
Unfortunately I don't know how to convert all the 536 (at once or in batch) files without freezing the computer.

I tried placing the files into 8 folders with 67 files in each and using the `convert` on the files of each group but the computer still froze.

Kindly provide me a way to efficiently combine those .tif files or convert them to .jpeg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for F in *.tif ; do convert $F $(basename $F .tif).jpg ; done` might work if you can convert a single file. This loops through all files and converts them individually.